# vba paste a value copied into a variable (application.onkey)

Tags: excel, vba

i ' ll explain what my problem is, what i want to get and how i would like to do but i can't.

So first here what i need,

i have some sort of calendar with some dates in it like this:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7NLO.png]

what i want to do is copy a value(string) in another cell but if in the other cell there is a value(string), the value in it and the value copied before they concatenate each other strings, something like that:

[image]

reading on internet i found what i need but i can't make it work,
i would like to pass the value copied with ctrl+c in to a variable and then with a custom shortcut paste in to another cell and if in the cell there is something they concatenate each other strings, like the picture above

i thought a code like this, but it does not work obviusly

```
    Sub g()
    Application.OnKey "^e", "test"

     End Sub


  Sub TEST()
 Dim l As String
  l = PasteSpecial

  If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
       ActiveCell.Value& " " & l
   ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
         ActiveCell.Value = l
  End If


  End Sub
```

i know it looks stupid what i wrote but  i don't know how onkey work

thanks in advance

Cristiano

Comment: Do you need it for a specific cell, or for an iteration between more such cells? Then, where from to be taken the value to be added?

Comment: no, not for a specific cell i need, one cell at the time but the cell could be anywhere

Comment: @FaneDuru the value can be taken from any cell but in the same row

Comment: I posted a code just adapting yours... Is it what you need?

Comment: @FaneDuru the code is ok but "my string"(l in your code) should be the value that i copied before with a ctrl+c,

Comment: like if i ctrl +c in a cell with "a" in it and then copy in a cell with "b" in it the final cell should be "a+b"

Comment: Then, you cannot put the Clipboard in a text variable, or you can but it is not appropriate. You should state that. I will make a code version copying from clipboard...

Comment: I posted a version copying from clipboard. I cannot understand why from clipboard, but if this is your wish, I tried doing as you say...

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next testing code. It can be adapted to work on a range iteration:

```
Sub TEST()
 Dim l As String
  l = "My String"

  ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value & IIf(ActiveCell.value = "", "", " + ") & l
End Sub
```

Or taking the value from another cell:

```
Sub TEST()
 Dim l As String
  l = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'the value in the second column refering the active cell

  ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value & IIf(ActiveCell.value = "", "", " + ") & l
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

My last attempt:

```
Sub testCopyfromTheSameRow()
  Dim ICol As Long
  
  ICol = 3 'The column number where the value to be copied
   ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value & ActiveSheet.cells(ActiveCell.row, ICol).value

End Sub
```

Comment: this will take as l the value in the second column from the active cell but the column is not fix  i need to take the value in the same row but from different columns

Comment: i tried this one  Sub PasteSpecialAdd()
   If ActiveCell.value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Else
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd
   End If
End Sub    but it does not work

Comment: @Cristiano Morresi: Are you sure that you know what you need, no offence? If yes, can you try asking in a way to make us understand what is to be done? What "different columns" should mean? What I posted was, **of course**, an example... I asked you about an iteration and you did not say anything. If you need a piece of code to do "what you need" you must better explain what this concept means.

Comment: no offence taken of course, yes i know what i need just i can't make it work, ok i'll try to explain myself better

Comment: @Cristiano Morresi: Before testing the code **did nou put something in the clipboard**? I mean, did you press Ctrl + C on the cell you want pasting its value? Do you understand the Clipboard concept?

Comment: just for example, in a range a1 to a10 i could have a string in a1 like "a"  then i ctrl +c (copy) the string and then i could have to paste it in a9 where could be a string like "b", then with the custom shourtcut, like ctrl+e i paste and i ll have "a+b", but the cell where i can find the string is not fixed, sometime could be in a1 onother in a5 and so on, i hope to make myslef clearer this time

Comment: @Cristiano Morresi: So, you need concatenation. Did you try the last code I put after the last editing? Does it what you need? Did you understand the (simple) code logic?

Answer (score 0):

finally i did it

this is the solution that i found thanks to @faneduru suggestion

Sub TEST()

```
    Dim l As String
      l = ActiveCell.Value

    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
       ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlvalue
    Else
       ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlvalue
       ActiveCell.Value = l & ActiveCell.Value
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: It is much better to avoid using clipboard. Modifying an existing cell value, it will keep its format, anyhow. Do you want manually copying cells and then using the above code? It is much simpler and faster to simple use `Activecel.Value = TheOtherCell.Value`. Of course, conditioning the emptiness as you see in my previous suggestions.

Comment: yes i want to copy manually and then use the code above, yes it's simpler, but i don't know what cell i am going to copy, for that i found easier copy manually and then paste with the code.

Comment: If you are not able to determine the logic behind the necessary cell finding, the code does not help you at all. You can faster manually paste the copied value... But, you may proceed as you want.

Comment: @faneduru i maybe found a way to avoid to use clipboard, Just out of couriosity why Is Better avoid to use clipboard? Forgive my manu questions and thanks fornthe help

Comment: The code simple needs more Excel resources and the code is not too fast. If you found such a way, good for you! Even if no need to find anything. My answer shows clearly how to proceed from this point of view...